# Rectangle Select for RDLC Report Designer in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, rdlc, report-designer

Does Rectangle Select functionality (viz., click, hold, and drag the mouse to create a selection) exist for the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 RDLC Report Designer?

**What I'm trying to do:**

After opening an existing RDLC file for editing in Design mode, I want to efficiently make room for a new text box in the middle of the report.

When I attempt to click and drag to select objects to move, the Rectangle Select doesn't appear.

**Installation Details**

Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Professional (v15.8) with two Microsoft Marketplace add-ons installed:

1. Microsoft RDLC Report Designer for Visual Studio (v14.2)
2. Microsoft Reporting Services Projects (v1.24)

The project uses NuGet package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms (v140.1000.523) to display the report.

Deploying and rendering works fine. This question just pertains to moving things in Design view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectangle Select seems to trigger only after a click+hold+drag starting **from the design surface** of the Report Header, Body, or Footer.

It seems a click+hold+drag starting from anywhere else (e.g., the whitespace outside the report) fails to trigger Rectangle Select.